# Python - Spyder displays error when trying to view Pandas dataframe inside dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, spyder

When I make a dictionary (dataframe collection) with a few datetimes and make a dataframe per dictionary with the following code:

```
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dates_list = [dt.datetime(2015,11,i+1) for i in range(3)]
month_day_list = [d.strftime("%m%d") for d in dates_list]

dataframe_collection = {} 

for month_day in month_day_list:
    new_data = np.random.rand(3,3)
    dataframe_collection[month_day] = pd.DataFrame(new_data, columns=["one", "two", "three"])
```

Then I can't view the individual dataframes inside the dictonary when I use Spyder.

The error I get is the following (printed approx. 20 times in the Spyder internal console) :

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\widgets\variableexplorer\dataframeeditor.py", line 277, in data return to_qvariant(self._format % value) TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'float'

When I print the dataframes, it works fine and it shows the right results.

If I write an intermediate dataframe, I can view the results in Spyder. The error starts when I place the dataframe inside a dict (or a defaultdict).

Any idea what could be wrong?

> [edit]:
>
> I really don't know what caused the error, I fixed it by completely deleting my Anaconda installation. I installed the 64bit version of Anaconda and now all is oke.

Comment: You were probably using an old Spyder version :-)

Comment: No it's not that easy. The versions of Spyder are exactly the same (except the 32 vs. 64 bit part).

Comment: I have the same issue and the problem is actually in the newer versions. I had to downgrade from Spyder 3.1.2 to 3.0.0 then the problem disappeared.